# Error handling during broadcasting message using WebSocketCollection object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

I'm currently using .Net 4.5 websocket package to support websocket service on windows 2012 server.

Using `WebSocketCollection` object I'm succesfully able to broadcast message to all the clients.

```
private static WebSocketCollection m_clients = new WebSocketCollection (); 
 m_clients.Broadcast(“Hello all”));
```

Here how to be sure all clients have received broadcasted messages? If some clients couldn't able to receive message how can I track those error messages? What king of error handling mechanism shall I need to use?

There is a onError virtual function. But I'm not sure how it will work during failure case of  broadcasted message.

```
 public virtual void OnError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not get the clients to "Acknowledge" the receipt of a packet, if a client does not Acknowledge the packet then chances are it wasn't received correctly.

If you are just wanting to keep the connection alive send a "Ping" message to the client before timeout.  Likewise you could code the client to Ping the server at a scheduled time, if no Ping received then that could indicate that there is a problem?